# Axios is not defined

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am using axios for building a simple weather app with React.js. I just completed the code but there is a problem. When I launch that app, it's not working at all and I see a reference error that says `axios is not defined`.

Here is my webpack.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './public/app/app.jsx',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './public/js/bundle.js'
    },
    externals: ['axios'],
    resolve: {
        root: __dirname,
        alias: {
            OpenWeatherMap: 'public/components/OpenWeatherMap.jsx',
            Main: 'public/components/Main.jsx',
            Nav: 'public/components/Nav.jsx',
            Weather: 'public/components/Weather.jsx',
            WeatherForm: 'public/components/WeatherForm.jsx',
            WeatherMessage: 'public/components/WeatherMessage.jsx',
            About: 'public/components/About.jsx'
        },
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['react','es2015', 'stage-0']
            },
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
        },{
            loader: 'json-loader',
            test: /\.json?$/
        }]
    }
};
```

and package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "weather",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple Weather App",
  "main": "ext.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Milad Fattahi",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.1",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "json": "^9.0.6",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.5.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^1.12.13"
  }
}
```

Comment: Well what file are you using axios in that you didn't import it?

Comment: I'm using axios only in OpenWeatherMap.jsx file and I imported axios in that file.

Comment: I tried `import axios from 'axios'` and `var axios = require('axios')` both but nothing changed.

Comment: try removing `externals: ['axios'],` from your webpack.config

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I know this might seem obvious but make sure there is a reference at the top of your file to the correct axios or install it 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've installed axios with npm and now it works correctly. The only mistake I had was excluding axios from webpack build.

Comment: I was having the same problem, until I placed the script tag above all my code. Makes perfect sense, as I was calling axios before it was even defined. Thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 29):

I forgot to import axios. I added to the top of my script:

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

I also forgot to install axios. I installed axios via npm using:

```
npm i axios --global 
// --global flags will save you the stress of insstalling axios again.
```

That solved my error.

Comment: --global can be added for globally installing axios

Comment: I was installing with --global but it didn't solve my problem, without --global it worked

Comment: ⚠️ Installing axios globally **is not a good practice**, this also will make the code only work on your local machine. You have to install it locally by project => `npm i axios`

Answer (score 14):

i think first u have to install
`npm install axios --save`
**then import it in app.js file**

```
import axios from "axios";
```

Answer (score 7):

You can add this at the top of the javascript file:

```
const axios = require('axios').default;
```

Answer (score 1):

https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js   <<linked this in my html (script src="")

Look on npm site if it changes https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

I then removed the following line from my js...

```
const axios = require('axios')
```

No more issues for me!

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answers include three main remedies, but there is a fourth potential remedy. I will repeat the already quoted ones for completion

**Remedy 1**

In the root project folder, install Axios:

```
npm i axios --global
```

**Remedy 2**

In the `.js` file that uses axios, import axios:

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

**Remedy 3**

Remove `externals: ['axios']`, from your `webpack.config`

**Remedy 4**

You are not calling axios to begin with through a spelling/case error. You may be calling something like `await Axios` as opposed to the correct call `await axios`.

Some tutorials like [this](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/process-an-api-response-in-react) one make the case typo and this causes great pain to the unsuspecting newcomer

Answer (score 0):

Phase 1:
Install Axios using terminal or CMD:

```
npm install axios --global
```

Phase 2:
Import library to your .js

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

Comment: Installing a lib globally is not a good practice and will make the code only work in your local machine!